# Print the values of an expression as a string

Tags: c#, .net

I want to take a math expression that takes variables and print (assign to string) the formula with the variables filled in.

```
int iTwo = 2;
int iResult = 0;

iResult = iTwo * iTwo;

string theString = (iTwo * iTwo).ToString();
```

In in the above code iResult = 4  and theString = "4"

I would like to do something that fills in the variables and returns the math expression like:

```
theString = (iTwo * iTwo).ExpressionToString();
```

and end up with theString = "2 * 2";

Thoughts?

Comment: Good ideas so far guys, but here is the complication... Today the expression could be:  itwo * itwo... but tomorrow the expression could be:  (itwo * itwo)/anotherVar... I need to convert any number of vars to their values and then convert to string (keeping operators, parentheses. etc. in place.  In other words I'll have different expressions that need to be evaluated and converted to strings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the `Expression<>` type.

```
public static string ExpressionToString<T>(Expression<Func<T>> e)
{
    var un = e.Body as BinaryExpression;
    if (un != null)
    {
        var left = un.Left.ToString();
        var leftEnd = left.Split('.').LastOrDefault();
        var right = un.Right.ToString();
        var rightEnd = right.Split('.').LastOrDefault();
        return e.Body.ToString().Replace(left, leftEnd).Replace(right, rightEnd);
    }
    return e.Body.ToString();
}

Console.WriteLine(ExpressionToString(() => iTwo * iTwo));

//prints (iTwo * iTwo)
```

You'll need to make the method more complex to parse things more complex than a simple binary expression, but that's the general idea.  You could just do `e.Body.ToString()`, but due to the way anonymous types are made for your lambdas, that can get ugly results, e.g.: `"(value(TestApp.Program+<>c__DisplayClass3).iTwo * value(TestApp.Program+<>c__Dis
playClass3).iTwo)"`.

Comment: This is nice because then he can compile the expression and execute it.

Answer (score 1):

With some operators overloading...

```
class Expression {

    string exprStr;

    public static explicit operator Expression(int value) {
        return new Expression() { exprStr = value.ToString() };
    }

    public static Expression operator *(Expression exp, int value) {
        return new Expression() { exprStr = exp.exprStr + " * " + value.ToString() };
    }

    public override string ToString() {
        return exprStr;
    }

}

class Program {
    static void Main() {
        int iTwo = 2;
        string theString = ((Expression)iTwo * iTwo).ToString();
    }
}
```

You would of course, need to overload the other operators you need in a similar way (e.g. `+`, `/` and so on).
You should also provide methods accepting other types than int if you need them, but the basic idea remains the same.

Note that you must cast to Expression only the first operand, otherwise you would get only the result to be converted.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Expression<>` and the parameter info stored in the expression to get what you want. Store your expression in an `Expression<>` variable.

```
int n1 = 4;
int n2 = 3;
Expression<Func<int, int, int>> exp = (arg1, arg2) => arg1 * arg2;

string expString = exp.ToString(); // (arg1, arg2) => arg1 * arg2
int startRHS = expString.IndexOf("=>") + 2; // starting index of RHS
string onlyRHS = expString.Substring(startRHS).Trim();  // arg1 * arg2

// replace args with values
string withValues = onlyRHS.Replace(exp.Parameters[0].Name, n1.ToString()); // 4 * arg2
withValues = withValues.Replace(exp.Parameters[1].Name, n2.ToString()); // 4 * 3
```

Though this is not the most robust solution, it works for simple scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

```
string ExpressionToString(int first, string operator, int second)
{
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
   sb.Append(first.ToString());
   sb.Append(operator);
   sb.Append(second.ToString());
   return sb.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static string ExpressionToString(params object[] param)
{
    return string.Join(" ", param.Select(t => t.ToString()).ToArray());
}
```

using:

```
string result = Helper.ExpressionToString(2, "*", 2 , ">=", -10);
//result = "2 * 2 >= -10";
```

Answer (score -1):

You could create your own method that called something similar to this:

```
public string ExpressionToString(int parameter1, string operator, int parameter2) {
  return string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", parameter1, operator, parameter2);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Please use create your method and use below code in it to achieve your requirement

```
string answer = string.Format("{0} {1} {2} = {3}", iTwo, iTwo, operator, result);
```